# Actionbar & tabsadapter: can I long press a tab?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using the actionbar with a tabsadapter. I'd like something to happen when the user long presses on a tab. I've been looking around for ways to add a longpresslistener to the tab, but I haven't found anything. Does anyone know if this is possible?

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never found a way to long press a tab. Instead, I overrided onTabReselected. When a user selects a tab, the fragment for that tab is displayed. When the user clicks the tab a second time, a menu appears. It works well.

Answer (score 2):

I use this workaround help method. Long press cannot be set directly but this works.

Basically it is getting tab View via custom view and setting long click listener on it.

```
public static void setTabLongClickListener(Context context, ActionBar.Tab tab, View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener)
    {
        //get previous view to ensure correct state after setting long click listener
        View previousCustomView = tab.getCustomView();

        //some view to get parent tab view
        View view = new View(context);
        tab.setCustomView(view);
        ((View)view.getParent()).setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);

        //return back removed custom view
        tab.setCustomView(previousCustomView);
    }
```

Tested on normal ActionBar, Support AppCompat and ActionBarSherlock.